# How to display multiple database rows as a single entry on web page

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, webforms

I'll try to set up a scene to make my example clear, but assume my SQL Server database has 2 tables, one with a persons name, DOB, favourite color and ID and another table with personID and email. This is a one to many relationship (many email addresses to 1 person). Let's assume there is only 1 person with 2 email addresses. When I display the results of a `SELECT *` on my webpage, I would see 2 rows, the only difference would be the email address (and ID but for this example, I won't display the result of ID).

My question is, how do we get around this to show it as only one 'item' and that the email is separated by a comma. Please consider these images as a before and after:

The data would appear twice due to their being 2 rows due to the join in the database:
[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Within my webpage, I order the results by ID taking a note of the current ID and comparing it with the previous ID of each iteration and if it matches, keep display the results of email until previousID is different to recentId. This would also mean previous taking note of the favourite color as a variable and displaying it when there are no more matching IDs (I hope this makes sense).

Is this OK or is there an elegant way when using EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using xml path:

```
select name, dob, substring(emails, 1, len(emails) - 1) as emails
from (
    select name, dob, (select email + ', '
                       from PersonEmail
                       for xml path('')) as emails
    from Person
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in the database that lists the emails.

```
CREATE FUNCTION PersonEmails
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @PersonID INT
) 

DECLARE @emailList VARCHAR(500)

SELECT @emailList = COALESCE(@emailList + ', ' , '') + email
    FROM PersonEmailTable
    WHERE PersonId = @PersonID

SELECT @emailList
```

Then call that function in your SQL Query

```
SELECT Persons.*, dbo.PersonEmails(Persons.ID) as Emails FROM Persons
```